# How can I analyze Google Voice data dump?

Tags: excel, google-voice

I use GV for business and have since about 2011.  Over that time I've amassed about 10,000 calls with various clients.  I'd like to analyze this data to understand things like what days of the week did I have the most calls, what months had the highest call volume, what hour of the day has the highest call volume, et cetera.  (Eventually I would also like to compare that to my Google Calendar data to analyze my conversion rates for a given month, but that's step 2)

My question is, is there any easy way to do this short of actually learning to use Excel?  Are there any free or relatively cheap statistics programs that will cut some of the work out for me?  It's easy enough to clean the data and drop it into Excel, but there are so many intermediary steps between having a good clean data set and actually getting a histogram out of it that it's starting to feel like it isn't worth it.

I have a list of about 10k calls in this format:

Col.A       Col.B        Col.C

client    date      24hr time

I'm not particularly concerned with who the client is... I just want to analyze the second two columns.

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest [learning R](http://www.r-project.org) for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks! I'll definitely check it out.  Looks very promising!

Comment: I did a similar analysis on my mobile use using R, so let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: why not just create a pivot table/pivot chart for the data  in Excel: its basically one step and much easier/faster than learning R